# Checker selecting faces to vertex group assigns faces in between

Tags: faces, vertex-groups

I'm trying to select a kind of checker selection on a circle and assign them to a vertex group.
I'd like to do this to then select the vertex group in the solidify modifier.

Unfortunately when I select and assign my faces to a vertex group, deselect and then select my vertex group, it selects the faces in between my selection.

I've tried to do the same by assigning the faces to a shader and that seems to work fine.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

**Selecting faces:**

[image]

**Assigning to vertex group:**

[image]

**Deselected the faces and then selecting the vertex group:**

[image]

**Wrong result with faces selected in between:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vertex groups create groups or vertices, it won't care about the faces you've selected, it will only take the selected vertices into account, so when you select these faces, it will take the vertices that are part of these faces into account. When you select back these vertex groups, it will automatically select the edges between these vertices as well, therefore it will select all the in-between faces. That said, since 2.8 (or 2.9) you now have Face Maps that allow you to select faces, see in the Object Data panel

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for pointing out. Unfortunately I can't use a Face Map with the solidify modifier. Nor can I extrude the faces since I have an animation going on that opens up the circle loop by loop like a camera lens that opens. So unfortunately I don't know how I can proceed with my effect. Guess I'll have to do something else. Thanks for pointing out man!

Comment: you just need to add topology, or please explain what you want to achieve more in details